# Understanding dsi system in device tree

Tags: drivers, port, device-tree

Let's say there is a video bridge like sn65dsi86. It has a driver ti-sn65dsi86.c in kernel source tree. It should be enabled with device trees. There an [example](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/devicetree/bindings/display/bridge/ti%2Csn65dsi86.yaml) for device tree. But it is not complete.

1. Is there somewhere fully functional example? (besides ti-sn65dsi86.yaml in Documentation)
2. What does this story about port, endpoint, remote-endpoint mean?

   ```
    ports {
      #address-cells = <1>;
      #size-cells = <0>;

      port@0 {
        reg = <0>;

        edp_bridge_in: endpoint {
          remote-endpoint = <&dsi_out>;
        };
      };

      port@1 {
        reg = <1>;

        edp_bridge_out: endpoint {
          data-lanes = <2 1 3 0>;
          lane-polarities = <0 1 0 1>;
          remote-endpoint = <&edp_panel_in>;
        };
      };
    };
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might find examples in the kernel source tree you are referring to if you search the compatibility string for the DSI bridge. If you don't, see [this](https://github.com/nxp-imx/linux-imx/blob/29549c7073bf72cfb2c4614d37de45ec36b60475/arch/arm64/boot/dts/renesas/r8a779a0-falcon-cpu.dtsi) for an example.

I'll try to describe **port**s, **endpoint**s and **remote-endpoint**s. See [here](https://github.com/devicetree-org/dt-schema/blob/main/dtschema/schemas/graph.yaml) for details, below is just (an incomplete) summary of it.

At the end, there an example taken from the source tree I referred above, with a few comments.

So, how do we represent connections between devices in the device tree?

- parent child

  e.g. in the example below, the bridge is on i2c1, address 0x2c
- phandles

  see [here](https://elinux.org/Device_Tree_Mysteries#Phandle) for a good description.

  e.g. see all the & within <> in the example below?
- ports, endpoints and remote-endpoints

  To represent more complex devices that can have multiple specifiable **port**s, each of which can be linked to one or more **port**s of other devices

  Each port node contains an **endpoint** subnode for each remote device **port** connected to this **port**

  Each endpoint should contain a **remote-endpoint** phandle property that points to the corresponding **endpoint** in the **port** of the remote device

  ```
    &i2c1 {

        bridge@2c {
            compatible = "ti,sn65dsi86";
            reg = <0x2c>;

            ports {
                #address-cells = <1>;
                #size-cells = <0>;

                /* port@0: Video port for MIPI DSI input */
                port@0 {
                    reg = <0>;
                    sn65dsi86_in: endpoint {
                        remote-endpoint = <&dsi0_out>;
                    };
                };

                /* port@1: Video port for eDP output (panel or connector)*/
                port@1 {
                    reg = <1>;
                    sn65dsi86_out: endpoint {
                        remote-endpoint = <&mini_dp_con_in>;
                    };
                };
            };
        };
    };


    &dsi0 {
        ports {
            port@1 {
                dsi0_out: endpoint {
                    remote-endpoint = <&sn65dsi86_in>;
                    data-lanes = <1 2 3 4>;
                };
            };
        };
    };

    / {

        mini-dp-con {
            compatible = "dp-connector";
            label = "CN5";
            type = "mini";

            port {
                mini_dp_con_in: endpoint {
                    remote-endpoint = <&sn65dsi86_out>;
                };
            };
        };

    };
  ```